# Format double to string in MQL (Monitoring Query Language) in GCP

Tags: gcloud

From the docs

> format   Format Int64, Double, or String as a String.
> Signature:   format(Num,   lit-String )   →   String
>           format(String,   lit-String )   →   String

> The format function takes two required arguments: an Int, Double or String, and a String. The function formats the first argument as a string, using the format specified in the second String argument, and returns the result as a String.

I'm trying to convert a `Double` datatype to `String` and used

```
fetch k8s_container
| metric logging.googleapis.com/user/my-metric
| group_by 1d, mean(val())
| map
  add[
      log: concatenate("License expiring in", format(val(), ""))
  ]
| condition val() <= 30
```

I'm not able to figure out what the `lit-String` is and how to use it inside `format` function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. "lit-string" is the "%s" for string. For other datatypes we can use "%f" for floating point numbers, "%d" for integers and so on.